# How can i connect BIRT framework to my JPA Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, birt

i am beginer to BIRT framework. Please could you any one please tell me the steps involved in connection between my JPA project Persistence.xml to BIRT application report dataSource. Could any one please solve this.....

Comment: As far as I understand, BIRT cannot read data directly over JPA layer. You either have to define direct database connection for BIRT (over JDBC and pure SQL) or provide data for BIRT reports over web service. I personally generate XML source for BIRT reports and then call BIRT to convert my XML to report.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea how to use this library. I'd propose to mention  in your question, that you're using a custom connector `birt-jpa-connector`.